# Creating slider menu for selecting an option using scroll view unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, menu, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I want to create an image select menu in unity somehow similar to this link:

http://www.slideshowbox.com/slideshow-templates-examples/simple-scale.html#flash

These images will also scroll on drag based on the distance dragged. After dragging images can have snapping effect.

Can anyone help me, how can I implement this thing in unity using scroll view. Or any other unity solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try [This Extension](https://bitbucket.org/ddreaper/unity-ui-extensions) for Snapping Scroll Rect to its child elements one by one.

Reference Post:

[UNITY UI Scroll through items one by one](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-ui-scroll-through-items-one-by-one.294523/)